# Shlokas, Mantras, Stotra, for Protection of Family?

Tags: mantras, shloka, stotra

Are there any Mantra, Stotra that can be chanted by Kid, for Protection of Father and Mother, Elderly Members of Famliy..

Protection From Diseases, Physical Dangers as Accident..etc..

Any, Stotra/etc..in which some Verses Describes,
Devotee pray God to Protect his/her Mother, Father..etc

Kid requesting God to protect his mother, father, family members

Chanted by one family member for protection of others in family.

Stotras may be have a Wrods, like MataRaksha, PitaRaksha, PutraRaksha

---

Some recommended me to, Do Contemplation..
To think, about God protecting Family, while chanting/hearing Ram Raksha Stotra./.
Please Tell Me Some, more detailed Contemplation.

Answer (score 5):

Refer Ramcharitmanas 1.27 - 1.28:

> rāma nāma narakēsarī kanakakasipu kalikāla.
> jāpaka jana prahalāda jimi pālihi dali surasāla.

> "The Name of Rāma is, as it were, the Lord manifested as a man-lion and the age of Kali, the demon Hiranyakashipu. Crushing this enemy of gods, the Name will protect the devotees repeating It, even as the Man-lion protected Prahlāda."||27||

> bhāyaom kubhāyaom anakha ālasahūom.
> nāma japata maṃgala disi dasahūom.

> "The Name repeated either with good or evil intention, in an angry mood or even while yawning, bestows blessedness in all the ten directions."||28||

Answer (score 4):

Here are few prayers for Lord Dhanvantari who is an Avatara of Lord Vishnu.

> śankham cakram jalaukam dadhad amṛta ghaṭam cāru dorbhis
> chaturbhiḥ|sūkṣma svachhan hṛdayaṁśuka parivilasan maulim ambhoja
> netram || kālam bhodojjvalāṅgam kaṭi taṭa vilasac cāru pitāmbarāḍyam |
> vande dhanvantarim tam nikhila gada vana prauḍa dāvāgni nīlām ||

Salutations to   Dhanvantari, who holds with his four arms -  A conch (success), a  wheel or disk of  energy (freedom),a leech (purity) and a pot celestial ambrosia (happy, long and fulfilled life), in whose heart shines a very subtle, clear, gentle and pleasing blaze of light, this light also shines all around his head and lotus eyes, who by his mere play destroys all diseases like a mighty forest fire.

> Om Namo Bhagavate Maha Sudharshana Vasudevaya Dhanvantaraye | Amrutha
> Kalasa Hasthaaya Sarva Bhaya Vinasaya Sarva Roka Nivaranaya || Thri
> Lokya Pathaye Thri Lokya Nithaye Sri Maha Vishnu Swarupa Sri
> Dhanvantri Swarupa | Sri Sri Sri Aoushata Chakra Narayana Swaha ||

I bow down and pray to the Lord Dhanvantari who is the incarnation of Lord Vishnu and called as Sudarshana Vasudev Dhanvantari. You hold in your hands, the Kalasha filled with the nectar of immortality. Oh Lord, you can remove all fears and diseases. You protect all the three worlds and you are the well wisher of all created beings. You are the Lord of Ayurveda and the manifestation of Lord Vishnu. You are the ultimate healer of all the living beings. We worship you and pray you.

> oṃ namo bhagavan vāsudeva dhanvantare | mahā-viṣṇu nārāyaṇa vaikuṇṭa |
> ārogyaṃ dehi dehi | dirghāyuṣyaṃ dehi dehi | śrī mūrtaye namas-svāhā
> ||

Salutations to the Lord Dhanvantari, the all-pervading Principle of Health,The omnipresent one, the Ground of all Being, the un-impreded one. Grant me health. Grant me long-life. Salutations to the manifestation of auspiciousness, May my health and longevity be used for the welfare of all sentient beings.

> Namani Dhanwanthary Aadi Devam | Surasura Vanditham Pada Padmam ||
> Loke Jara Rugbhay Mrityu Nashakam | Datharam Eesham Vividhaushadhinam
> ||

I bow down in front of you Lord Dhanvantari. Your lotus feet is respectfully worshipped by the Dods and Demons. You have infinite powers to save the people from the miseries of diseases, ageing, fear of death and other sufferings. Oh Lord, please bless me with your grace and medicines so that I can also help the people with cures from their diseases.

Answer (score 3):

As OP is asking something that can be chanted by Kid (or not?), I know only two of them which I think a kid can chant, and I was told as a kid!

**Shubham Karoti**

Many might already know about it, Shubham Karoti is a short shloka which is dedicated to oil lamp. Its meaning is straightforward, it can be chanted by anyone after enlightening the oil lamp at evening. In Marathi version there are certain changes in 2nd verse as well as its extended.

> Shubham Karoti Kalyaannam-Aarogyam Dhana-Sampadaa |
> Shatru-Buddhi-Vinaashaaya Diipa-Jyotir-Namostute ||
> Diipa-Jyotih Para-Brahma Diipa-Jyotir-Janaardanah |
> Diipo Haratu Me Paapam Diipa-Jyotir-Namostute ||

In Marathi Version:

> Divya divya Deepak kaar
> Kani kundala moti haar
> Divyala pahun namaskaar
> Namaskaar |
> Diva jalato deva pashi
> Ujed padala tulshi pasha
> Maza namaskaar
> Sarva devanchya paya pasha|

> Gharatil pida baher jaude
> Baherchi laxmi gharat yevu de
> Gharchya dhanyala ani Tanhya Baalala udanda
> AaUshya laabho|
> Morya morya mi baal tahane |
> Tujich seva karukay jaane ||
> Anyay maje kotyan koti |
> Moreshwara wa tu kaal koti |

**Maruti Stotra**

Written by Samarth Ramdas Swami, It clearly Mentions in its Falshruti:

> Bhoot-Pret Sambadhadhi, Rog-Vyadhi Samastahi Nasati-Tutati ChinTa Aanande Bhim Darshane |

> Any relation with Bhoota or Preta, any Diseases or stress is resolved providing Happiness!

Note that: you will discover two distinct maruti Stotras, one is Bhimroopi Maruti Stotra (This is simpler and the one I am stating but is in marathi, I dont think marathi is very different than hindi) other is in sanskrit which contains Beeja, can be found [here.](https://hi.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0#:%7E:text=%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%82,%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%20%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%AE%20%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%20%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%20%E0%A5%A4)

Comment: not necessarily, Chanted by Kid - only.. even..Elder chanting for Protection of Other Elders in Home..etc